# Longest common subsequence Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need longest common subsequence function in postgresql. Typicall installation hasn't function for it. I wrote code on plpgsql, but it works slow. Are there some addons(or something) for postgres with such function?

Edit: I need compare 2 strings, but not with = operator and not like. For example if I have to find abcba, result can be adbcbdac. For this I want to implement LCS(longest common subsequene, not string)

Edit: I've found some extension for postgre called fuzzystrmatch, but it only works for max 255byte texts. Does anyone know some analogue of that extension?

Comment: Please tell us more about the algorithm you have coded. Are you aware that this is an NP-hard problem in general?

Comment: yes I now that it's NP hard. I've 2 sequences and coded dynamic O(N ^ 2) solution

Comment: There are some similar requests/answers at DBA SE with sample code: e.g. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15808/13250 P.S. Is your algorithm based on Hirschberg's?

Comment: It's standard dynammic programming solution. I don't know Hirschberg's algo :)

Comment: Hirschberg, D.S. An information-theoretic lower bound for the longest common subsequence problem. Information Processing Letters, Vol.7, No.1, 1978.
A.V. Aho, D.S. Hirschberg and J.D. Uilman, Bounds on the complexity of the longest common subsequence problem, J. ACM 23 (1) (January 1976).
D.S. Hirschberg, A linear space aigorithm for computing
maximal common subsequences, Comm. ACM 18 (6) (June 1975) 341-343.
D.S. Hirschberg, Algorithms for the longest common
subsequence problem, J. ACM 24 (3) (October 1977).

Comment: Post what you have in plpgsql and we may be able to improve on it.

Comment: Examine http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html, http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed . I also have the feeling that it might be possible to create a custom GiST index method that'd be helpful for this problem, though index sizes might get impractical.

Comment: Craig thanks for advice, but I need something else. pg_trgm is for trigraph problem

Comment: Deer thanks for answer, I think Hirschbergs algo will help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Erwin, Craig and the Deer Hunter that you could provide more information by telling us what kind of comparison you are making? 
Let's assume you compare text files and it is sufficient to compare complete lines. 
Then could you compare the lines from the shortest file to the lines of the longest file. A comparison has three possibilities:
1. a line from file A does not match with any line in file B,
2. a line from file A does match with a line in file B.
3. a line from file A does match and both lines are consecutive to the previous match.
If it is situation 1 close any open object. if there exists an open object, add it to an array. If it is situation 2 and there is no open object, create a new one. If there is an open object, then should it be a situation number 3, hence add the line (or linenumber) to the open object.
Run through both files executing this comparison and you will find your answer, because the object with the maximum number of lines (or number of characters) will be your LCS.

I would however perform this kind of operation in another language then plpgsql. In my case would it be Java or PHP. Just get the data into this type of language and do the job. Those languages are much better equiped for this type of action.